# Hyper-V Quick Create on Server

Tags: hyper-v

Windows 10 Creators Edition has come out with a Quick Create VM option on Hyper-V.  Does anyone know how to add this functionality to Windows Server.  2012 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyper-V Quick Create isn't available in Windows Server, so it isn't possible to add it.

Comment: Thanks.  I searched, but though I was having a "bad google day".

Comment: Not impossible since the server and desktop OS's share kernels. It may be possible to add in Windows server 2019, but I haven't figured it out YET. The one component that is of use for business use is the Ubuntu image because all of the integrations are undocumented at best on how to get everything to run the same as a quick create VM for video performance and responsiveness. For now create on a workstation, create export and import on the server host.

Comment: It's not possible natively or by design. If you hack it to make it work that's your prerogative.